# Node Express route handler -- tell if user clicked link to issue request or manually typed into URL bar?

Tags: express

I have route request handler that takes a request parameter that should match a key in a data structure...when the corresponding object to that key is found, the requester gains access to that object.

The problem is that the request handler should only really be triggered when the user who is about to gain access clicked on a generated link that is emailed to them via an invite -- there is nothing preventing a random user from making a lucky guess as to what the unique key might be and gaining access to the object when they weren't actually invited.

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/:creator', function (req, res) {
  var path = req.params.creator.toLowerCase();
  for(booth in boothList) {
    var boothID = boothList[booth].creator.toLowerCase();
    if (path == boothID) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
    }
  }
});
```

Again, the situation is this:

Say the first user creates a booth with the unique name "Me"...they send an invite email to somebody with the link `http://www.myappsite.com/Me`, that invited person can click the link and join the booth as they should be able to...the problem is that an uninvited user can just manually type into their URL bar `http://www.myappsite.com/Me` and join the booth as if they were invited even though they were not.

How can I ensure that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll always be dependent on the size of the link itself. Bigger and randomly created names are harder to guess and find just by using brute force as an attack vector. If you let your users choose their own name they will probably go for short and easy names, the same kind of names that are easy to guess just by doing a simple dictionary attack. You can't do a lot of magic about that, unless you start to use other data to validate the incoming request (like ip address, etc.)

You can increase the size of the generated link and make it harder to guess. For example, the user chooses the name `foo` for their key, but you can generate something that looks like `https://example.com/SRJsWVTxIxYAcPErxwqG7h/foo`. Assuming that the random string was generated by a cryptographically secure RNG then you are almost sure that the chances of someone using brute force and getting a valid key are relatively low.

Of course that the increasing number of valid keys on your system will also increase the chance of an attacker being able to guess a key just by sending random strings. You can have a technical read about the birthday problem using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

There are a lot of other ways to protect your system against guessing, but if you just want to share emails and you don't want the users to agree on some kind of password to protect the link then the link expansion is the easiest solution.

But it will be nice to read other persons opinions on this matter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I had a suspicion that I would have to prepend a salt+hash or something like that to the URL, but was hoping for a more direct solution. I'll let this question sit for a few hours before I accept your answer, just in case there is something like what I'm looking for.